# Why does the catch block produce a compiler error?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have the following contrived code :

```
class Exception
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int x = 10;
        int y = 0;

        int result;

        try{
            result = x / y;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("Throwing the exception");
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        catch(Exception ae){
            System.out.println("Caught the rethrown exception");
        }
    }
}
```

The first catch block rethrows the exception that was caught. The compiler however says "Incompatible Types" and "Throwable" required. Why is this error produced?

Comment: In `catch(Exception ae)` it recognizes `Exception` as your own class.

Comment: Rename class , Make it something diff. than Exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change you class name from `Exception to Exception1.`

**It looks like name conflicting issue.**

Your Naming convention strategy is Against of Java Identifier define rule.

Means, you can not give name which is already given by library. here, class name.

Comment: Why does the code compile then if I have named my class 'Exception' and there is already a class 'Exception' in java.lang?

Comment: Yes I'm using eclipse

Comment: Try closing  your class, open again and run it.

Comment: Compiles, I've tried it in Windows as well with the command line and it compiles.

Comment: kevin, compiler just check, is there any identifier which match with reserved keyword ? if found then error comes. Here, scenario is Class name match with other class name not like keyword we are using. right ?

Comment: ultimately compiler pass success because You follow Naming convention rules properly. You can gives as many as you want class name same. but only restriction is that same name Class must be reside into different package. i hope now you are clear.

Comment: @vishalgajera The compiler doesn't give two hoots for naming conventions. It cares about the syntax and semantics of the language only.

Comment: It compiles because it is legal Java. There are countless examples of name clashes in different packages. That's what packages are for: to disambiguate name clashes.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Exception` class is hiding `java.lang.Exception` and You are trying to throw your own class as exception. You should throw an object that extends java.lang.Exception class.

Just change Exception with java.lang.Exception

```
catch(java.lang.Exception ae)
```

Or change the name of your class which is hiding `java.lang.Exception`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change your class name from Exception to another user-define name.

it is name conflicting issue because Exception is a inbuilt

class in java so you can't give the same name in your source code.

It just like you can not use keyword as an identifier in java. 
 Exception is not a keyword but it's already use as a class identifier.

Answer (score -1):

When a function can throw and exception you need to declare that in the function header.

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html

Comment: That applies to checked exceptions only, and your citation says so. The only exception that is thrown out of this method is `ArithmeticException`, which is a `RuntimeException`, which is not a checked exception. NB the Java Tutorial is not a normative reference.